# Creating measure tool that can be used on 3D model on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, 3d-model, point-cloud

I have a 3D-Point cloud model of a rock formation that I want to upload onto ArcGIS Online.

Is there a way to create a tool for the web user to determine distance across the surface of the model, and also to determine volume of a layer that the user can draw?

I have separated the different geological layers into multipatches and would like the ability to determine the volumes of a section of the layer based on a user drawing input.

Comment: I think you should submit an ArcGIS Idea for this and then link to that, and describe it briefly, in a self-answer.